# Black hole energy and momentum in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, black-holes

Can the total energy and momentum of a black hole be described using the usual expressions in special relativity, namely
\begin{equation}
E = \gamma mc^2
\quad
\text{and}
\quad
p = \gamma mv
\end{equation}
if the black hole is observed at infinity?

Comment: I believe the answer is yes, since there is nothing that distinguishes a collapsed black hole with mass $M$ from any other object with the same mass when viewed far away; all GR metrics asymptote to the flat SR metric at infinity.

Comment: @jsborne *all GR metrics asymptote to the flat SR metric at infinity* Cosmological metrics don’t have to.

Comment: I apologize, thanks for catching that; I was thinking of the Kerr-Newman metric, where the cosmological constant is zero.